# Why when calling ExtJS Grid Store Load too many requests are executed?

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, grid

In my page I have 2 different ExtJs grid. Is the first grid is loaded more than once, when sorting a column, 3 request are executed trying to load data for grid.

Sorting:

```
grid.store.sortInfo = { field: name, direction: dir };
grid.store.load({ params: { ... });
```

Load grid:

```
grid.destroy();
// common grid setup
```

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have `remoteSort` set to true? Additionally, `buffered stores` **automatically** set this to true.  This could be the culprit.  More info available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteSort)